# Ffmpeg keeps writing text to my mate terminal

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

Whenever I open a mate-terminal, I get superfluous text from ffmpeg.

It's the same text every time. ?

Is there a way to stop it?

When I removed ffmpeg completely, my mate terminal still shows

```
Command 'ffmpeg' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install ffmpeg  # version 4.1.4, or
sudo apt  install ffmpeg

See 'snap info ffmpeg' for additional versions.

andy@7_~/Downloads/$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an ffmpeg command somewhere in your bashrc (or other files that automatically get executed when opening a shell). Make sure there isn't any occurrence of ffmpeg (or anything that uses ffmpeg) as a command in the following files:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`

Comment: @ Tim Schumacher Yes you are right. I had alias mp42mp3=MOV="$";FILENAME=$(basename "${MOV// /_}" | sed 's/(.)-.*/\1/').mp3;ffmpeg -i "${MOV}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 "${FILENAME}" in bash alias. Once it was removed my problem was solved